# Mouse flickering in horizontal band region of screen

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors, display, mouse, flicker

EDIT September 6, 2020: Still stuck with this problem, does anyone have any ideas, it's miserable when my mouse pointer disappears, often for many seconds at a time :(

EDIT: (even) more symptoms/data at bottom:

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, and my mouse pointer has a vile habit of flickering. For the longest time I though it was just my old eyes couldn't see it when I was trying to find it somewhere on the three displays I have. However, I've pinned down the fact that it for sure flickers, so it's not entirely my weakness! When it's flickering, it essentially disappears entirely while it's moving.

On two of the screens, there will be a horizontal band of about 1/5th of the total height. If the mouse is stationary in that region, it will flicker quite fast ending up much less bright as a result. If I *move* the pointer in this region, the mouse will essentially vanish from view.

The band of the screen that causes this migrates slowly from top to bottom of the display, perhaps taking 25 seconds to do so. I'm not sure if the timing is exact or not, it doesn't seem like it is, but I can't assert any certainty. Further, the effect is not always visible. For minutes at a time, all will be well, but then it'll start doing it again, and the region in which the mouse flickers will progress cyclically from top to bottom of the screen and repeat.

On my three screens, it seems that sometimes it's doing this on one or two screens, but often it's not all of them at the same time. When it's doing it on two that are side by side, the position of the region of bad behavior is frequently *different* from one screen to another (that is, if I find the height of the flickery part on one screen, and move the mouse horizontally to the next screen, it'll quit flickering. Then I move up/down on that screen and can find a different region where the flicker occurs.)

I've seen lots of discussions about this going back years. I do not have an "unknown" monitor, I don't have a "green" monitor icon in my displays config. I am, as far as I can be, pretty sure that my monitors refresh rates are correct; at any rate, two of them report 1920x1080@60Hz on the monitors themselves, and xrandr says that's the preferred rate for those monitors. I do not, however, see how I would change this anyway.

One oddity in my setup is that one of my 1920x1080 displays is running at a scale factor of 0.666 (i.e. it's pretending to be 1280x720, so the fonts are readable). However, I only started doing that recently and the cursor was misbehaving before that (that is, I would regularly have grave difficulty finding it, then suddenly it would be obvious) so I don't think that has any effect (plus, the effect is at different times visible across all three monitors, not just that one).

Another feature of my configuration is that one of the monitors is a tablet device, with a pen. It provides a USB output that simulates a mouse. That runs in parallel with my regular wireless mouse.

EDIT: So, it seems that this problem perhaps only starts occurring after the machine has been running for a while, or perhaps is triggered by starting a virtualbox windows client. I'm still trying to determine which, and it's possible that it starts by itself, but is exacerbated by the virtualbox client running. It's a little hard to test, since this is a main server that hosts a number of things (including a headless guest OS) that are very inconvenient to shut down. I'll update as I'm able to get more data, but for now, it looks like this could have a virtualbox element.

Second EDIT: I discovered that two screens were running at 60 Hz and one at 60.02. I altered the sync rate on that third screen to 60.00, and the situation changed. Well, it's improved, I guess, but not fixed. Aside from the fact that the only way to change the sync rate on the third screen was to choose undesireable (low, and not-native) pixel dimensions, the cursor flicker still happens, but seemingly less. So, it appears that in some way refresh rate is involved, but having "identical" rates of 60.00Hz on all three has not fixed the issue.

Comment: Sounds complex.  Well done for getting it working to some degree.  One old trick is in your displays make sure there is a gap between them.  So that one display does not overlap another. Then look at what compositing you are using. Try to change that.

Comment: Thanks @walttheboss, I do know how to create gaps, so I'll try that. But I don't even begin to know what "compositing" I'm doing... The only thing I have done (from the "I did this" sense) is to position the displays, set their resolutions, and the scale of one. All with xrandr. Where should I look to find out about this compositing thing?

Comment: Please edit your question with the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: oops, sorry, I thought I'd put that in there. Updated...

Comment: I tried to make a gap between the displays, by using xrandr to set an absolute position, but the result has no gap, xrandr reports the position right up against the adjacent screen, and has removed the gap. How should I be doing that?

Comment: @walttheboss I've made no progress, is there a chance you could point me at a reference on "compositing", and perhaps something on making the gap you described? As I mentioned, I thought I knew how to do this, but after positioning screens with a discontinuity in X coordinates, xrandr seemed to recalculate and closed things up!

Comment: Oh but you have made progress.  If you have tried and failed and learned that is great progress.

Answer (score 1):

In Kubuntu you have more control over the settings. That is neither good nor bad. In my image you can see I can select between different ways that that graphics works.
[image: Kubuntu 20.04 display settings]

Another thought is refresh rate.  I am an an engineer and you mentioned the band of invisibility(hereafter "the BOI) moves down the screen.  That begs the refresh rate of the screen(s).  Some displays can only handle one.  If your machine is refreshing the screen(s) in a way the display can't handle then you will get that BOI feature.

When you enable fractional scaling you will get a refresh rate dropdown.  Try changing that.

[image: Ubuntu 20.04 Display Settings]
[image: Ubuntu 20.04 Display Settings Fractional]

Comment: Oh wow...  I get nothing of that kind in my graphical configuration too. I have orientation, resolution and scale (which offers 100% and 200%). There's a display arrangement thing at the top, and "night light" at the bottom. I made the scaling work using xrandr directly. That's also how I configure my primary display. When I look at the displays with xrandr, they only list a single refresh rate against the selected resolution for the monitors.

Comment: However, I also notice that two monitors are set at 60.00Hz, and one is set at 60.02 (these numbers are all followed by an asterisk and a plus sign, which I think means they're the monitor's preferred scaling and refresh rate) is it possible the difference is what triggers the problem? Is linux/X11 capable only of running at a single rate across all the screens, perhaps, and this is throwing something off? I will note that the cursor plays flicker-hide-and-seek on all the displays, not just one.

Comment: I will run the third monitor at 1280x720, which looks horrible/grainy, but defaults to 60Hz. I'll check to see if that makes the problem go away.

Comment: And just to nudge the thread, this did not fix the problem. It changed the timing a little, seeming like a bit of an improvement, but it didn't fix it :(

Answer (score 1):

ISSUE RESOLVED!

I was just taking a stab here but it worked! I commented the following line out of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

```
Section "Device"
#  Option     "SWCursor" "true"
```

After a reboot my cursor no longer flickers! It *also* corrected another issue where my desktop would turn black, then I could click to sort of.. redraw it.

Comment: Oh, interesting! I've been using Xfce for the last two years, as that didn't have the problem, but it would be nice to have the same window manager on all my boxes. I shall try this when I can afford a little down-time. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to... mask this issue completely by using software to share the mouse (and keyboard) from another computer. I'm using synergy, though I expect barrier would have the same result.

Not exactly a fix, but it does relieve the symptom and maybe that will give somebody smarter than me a hint on how to actually fix this.

Comment: Another thing I've found that resolves _this_ issue (though presents many others) is choosing to render everything in software. In my case I installed the cinnamon theme which comes out of the box with an option at login to render everything in software. Terrible solution, but again this is just information to hopefully help somebody smart figure out how to fix this. Seems to be hardware related in any case.